# Update panel and Repeater toggle function

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, updatepanel

After placing an Update panel to my repeater detail division repeater is collapsing on each click of Edit Button or other button.(Repeater is having header and detail division with toggle function)
I have a hidden filed which help to edit update... with out collapsing the detail division.Before adding the update panel when i click the Edit button in the detail section of repeater,Textboxes will become enable and will show Cancel and save button with out collapsing.After adding the Update panel EDIT,UPDATE,SAVE,CANCEL every thing is working fine but for each click the detail section is collapsing and i have to expand for doing the UPDATE. After adding Update panel all code in Item command is working fine except collapsing issue on Click of edit mentioned above.

Code is as follows

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>      
     <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
<ItemTemplate>

 <div id='h<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "ItemIndex") %>' class="heder"
      onclick='ToggleDisplay(<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "ItemIndex") %>);' style="border-style: none; font-weight: normal;">

     <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" Height="30px" BorderStyle="None" BackColor="#DCE4FA">
      <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnItemIndex" runat ="server" Value='<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container, "ItemIndex") %>' />
          <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LicenseID")%> 

   </asp:Panel> 
   </div>

  <div id='d<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "ItemIndex") %>' class="details">


     <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Height="195px" BackColor="Gray" Font-Bold="False"  ForeColor="Maroon">
    <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"LicenseName")%>' Enabled="false" BackColor="Gray"  BorderStyle="None"></asp:TextBox>
       <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" CommandName="edit"  CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LicenseID") %>' Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" >Edit</asp:LinkButton>

                              </asp:Panel>
       </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:Repeater>

 </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code Behind

```
     Protected Sub Repeater1_ItemCommand(source As Object, e As  System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterCommandEventArgs) Handles Repeater1.ItemCommand

    If e.CommandName.ToLower() = "edit" Then
        Dim hdnItemIndex As HiddenField = DirectCast(DirectCast(e.CommandSource, LinkButton).NamingContainer.FindControl("hdnItemIndex"), HiddenField)
        Dim myScript As String = "ToggleDisplay(" + hdnItemIndex.Value & ");"

        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType](), "RegisterStartupScript", myScript, True)

    End If

  For Each rptItem As RepeaterItem In Repeater1.Items
        Dim Textbox1 As TextBox = DirectCast(rptItem.FindControl("Textbox1 "), TextBox)
        If Textbox1 IsNot Nothing Then
            Response.Write(Textbox1.Text)
        End If
    Next
  If e.CommandName = "edit" Then

 DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("TextBox2"), TextBox).Enabled = True
        DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("Textbox2"), TextBox).BorderStyle = BorderStyle.NotSet
        DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("Textbox2"), TextBox).BackColor = Drawing.Color.White

 End if
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to accomplisch this,

first

```
</ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Yourcontrol" EventName="YourEvent" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Second:

You can also use AJAX (Not the .NET easy version)

Instead of using the .NET AJAX library (wich is quit havy. You can add some script posting a string to a specific URL. That URL will then perform whatever you like

```
function btnAddMeter() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "MeterIntake.aspx/AddMeter?"
                + "discipline=" + $('#ddlDisciplines').val()
                + "&meterType=" + $('#ddlMeteringType').val()
                + "&description=" + $('#ddlDescription').val()
                + "&meternumber=" + $('#txtMeterNumber').val(),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                try {
                    if (data.d == "Invalid") {
                        document.getElementById('lblValidation').innerHTML = "Ongeldige invoer!";
                    }
                    if (data.d == "Exists") {
                        document.getElementById('lblValidation').innerHTML = "Meter is reeds eerder binnengeboekt";
                        document.getElementById('txtMeterNumber').value = "";
                        document.getElementById('txtMeterNumber').focus();
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#ScanTable > tbody:last')
                            .append("<tr>" +
                            "<td>" + data.d.discipline + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + data.d.meterType + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + data.d.description + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + data.d.meternumber + "</td>" +
                            "</tr>");
                        document.getElementById('txtMeterNumber').value = "";
                        document.getElementById('txtMeterNumber').focus();
                        document.getElementById('lblValidation').innerHTML = "";
                    }
                }
                catch (e) {
                    alert("Error in service! Please try again");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

You should replace that with your own code / controls.

Hope it helps.